Java with Habarta typescript generator nullable/undefined handling
I have common java app with https://github.com/vojtechhabarta/typescript-generator for generating typescript api from java DTOs model.
Mostly it works okay, but i got to a situation, when I need to differentiate between null and undefined.
Lets say I have a class
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
}

This will result in typescript definition like this.
export interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

That means both fields are required from the typescript point of view. I could make them optional using @Nullable annotation
public class Person {
    @Nullable
    private String name;
    @Nullable
    private Integer age;
}

and configuring this in the plugin.
<optionalAnnotations>
  <optionalAnnotation>jakarta.annotation.Nullable</optionalAnnotation>
</optionalAnnotations>

Result would be like this:
export interface Person {
    name?: string;
    age?: number;
}

But now the problem is this. I want to implement the PATCH endpoint and differentiate between value not present and value being null. I could make that in java by using optional (altough Optional is not recommended for fields, Jackson library works well with this and correctly handles the 3 states (optional being null, optional being empty and optional with value present).
public class PersonPatch {
    private Optional<String> name;
    private Optional<Integer> age;
}

Event typescript generators handles these, just like before.
export interface PersonPatch {
    name?: string;
    age?: number;
}

However, now, java supports 3 states for the fields and javascript doesnt. It only supports undefined or non-null value. I would like the typescript definition to be like this:
export interface PersonPatch {
    name?: string | null;
    age?: number | null;
}

And event that is possible with habarta plugin, by specifying
<optionalPropertiesDeclaration>questionMarkAndNullableType</optionalPropertiesDeclaration>

But this applies nullable to every optional field there is. I dont want the Person definition to be affected, just the PersonPatch definition.
Is that possible? I found there is  tag in plugin config but this does not seem to work at all.
How do you handle this? Should I use other way for the java model? Or other library for Typescript generation? What do you think?
Thanks
